# Retrieve Firebase cloud function url from within a mobile app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can I get the Firebase function url/ metadata from the console from within a mobile app

I have just completed the sample tutorial for Firebase Cloud Functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello Wolrd!");
 console.log("Hello World function triggered");
});
```

If I wish to call this function from my ios app I could call the url

```
https://us-central1-menu4me-?????.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld
```

Which I can see in from Firebase deploy and also see it in my Firebase console
[image]

I don't understand how I could retrieve this url without hard coding it in my app.

Comment: Calling a Cloud Function is no different from calling any other URL in your app. You'd indeed likely hard-code the URL. What is the problem you see with that?

Comment: How can it be guaranteed that the URL will nor change? Perhaps  a different server or something.

Comment: The URL doesn't identify a server. It identifies a container in a data center. Neither of those will change, unless you change them.

Comment: Perhaps, but If I changed them it would break the app, I suppose that the "us-central1" could be a parm in remote config or similar.

Comment: I understand Firebase is currently all hosted in the US, imagine it would change in the future

Comment: If new regions are introduced, existing projects/containers will stay where they are unless you change them. They won't auto-change. If you want to future-proof for changes, you could indeed make it a configuration parameter.